# need to call a struts action for every particular interval time and the result need to reflect in jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2, action, intervals

I need to call a struts-action for every particular interval time and the result need to reflect in front end (*.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript(jQuery):

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $(selector).load(yourAction);
    }, pauseTime);
});
```

Explaination:
`selector` indicates the content that should be refreshed
`yourAction` indicates your action which you are calling
`pauseTime` indicates the life time of your page.

Comment: Hi, Thanks 4 ur answer.... pauseTime means interval time? and If i redirected to another page, still tha functio calls tha action?

Comment: pauseTime means interval time. i am not sure what you mean redirect to another page, the snippet should wraped with `<script>` and it will be loaded on page load.

Comment: maybe mention for the uninitiated that you are also making use of jQuery with the dollar signs?